# Creating envelopes where first signer specifies next recipient(s)

Tags: docusignapi

I need to send out a document / envelope. I'm using the C# SDK, since we'll be sending from a service. We know who the recipients of the document COULD be, but it's up to the first recipient to either sign or choose a recipient.

The first recipient of the document can do one of two things-

1. Sign the document
2. select a different recipient from a drop-down list of Roles, and then have the document go to that user for their signature.

   - these future roles are "Dealer" and "Lawyer". We'll know, at the time of 
     selection who these user's are (names & emails).

Right now, I have a template (from Word), with tabs that will be populated when sending the initial envelope, so that all users can see the data.

My question(s) are:

1. Is using the Template the best option? Should I attempt to update the text within the Word document, by not having it configured as a template?
2. How should I add the users / roles / signers to the envelope, since they can be chosen ? I saw something about Intermediaries - is this what I should be using to specify the next recipient in the document? Currently, I have three "Roles" defined in my template- one for "Provider" - the first recipient, then "Dealer" and "Lawyer".
3. IF not using a Template, how should I specify / add the follow-up users, "Dealer" and "Lawyer"?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you're going to want Conditional Recipients, which is coming soon, but not ready yet. 
For the time being, do the Signer, Dealer and Lawyer roles all take the same actions, or will there be different tags depending on who's signing?

Comment: Thanks Drew. The way it works is like this:

1. Document / Envelope is sent to Provider.
2. Provider either signs document, or sends to "Dealer" role user.
3. If Dealer role gets document, they can either:
       a. sign the document
       b. select to send it to the "Lawyer" role, and then must also sign it.
4. If the "Lawyer" get it, they just sign it, and that's the end. 

So its like we have 1, 2 or 3 signers.

When is the ConditionalRecipients feature coming out?

Answer (score 0):

1. Using a template is probably what you need. You can update the document inside a template before sending an envelope that is created from the template. (you can also use"correct" to update an envelope that was sent, but only by the original sender and there are some other limitations)
2. see comment from Drew, you cannot do a conditional recipient yet, but there are other options, including a special type of recipient that can add other recipients (if that's what you want).
3. You can create a more complex workflow that have the first envelope trigger a second envelope with the recipients you want. That could work for you. Not sure yet about all your requirements, but the first signer can trigger this using our web-hook from connect.

Comment: Thanks Inbar! See my response to Drew above. I think the other option is what I would need- how can I do that via the API? 

Your option #3 is interesting- we would have to track & capture the 2nd envelope in that case. Could that Envelope have the signed document from my step #1 as part of it, so that the "Dealer" and or "Lawyer" users can view who signed and when?

Comment: yes! you could take the completed doc from the first envelope and use it as the document to the second envelope. That's easy to do. Let me know if you need additional help